# React.JS Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and want to do my first steps but get stuck on a probably very basic error. I did read the other threads to this topic, but I could not derive a solution for my problem out of them.
Please help! Thank you!

Error Message

```
Uncaught Error: MyTable(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="myTableNOjsx.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

myTableNOjsx.js

```
class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
      
  render(){ 
  return
    React.createElement("table", null,
        React.createElement("tr", null, 
            React.createElement("td", null, "${this.props.first}"), 
            React.createElement("td", {style: "text-align: right"}, "${this.props.second}")
        )
    )
   ;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyTable, {first: "erste", second: "zweite"}, null),
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

EDIT: `<script src="myTableWITHjsx.js"` to `<script src="myTableWITHjsx.js"`

Comment: "I am new to React and want to do my first steps" -- please use https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html instead of a strange non-JSX setup like that then.

Comment: I have never seen anyone write a react application like this.

Comment: I want to integrate React into an existing website written in php, completely changing the stack and the toolchain is not possible. I do not develop it from scratch! By the way the version with JSX brings the same error!

Comment: You must not have a new line after `return` - this is what is returning `undefined`

Comment: Could it be that you are loading the wrong script? Example says myTableWITHjsx is loaded but you are showing us myTableNOjsx.js code

Comment: change `"${this.props.first}"` to `\`${this.props.first}\`` in both places, those are template literals. shouldn't be enclosed in `""`

Comment: @A Macdonald: Edited that! But that was not the source of error! Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the new line between `return` and `React.createElement`.
A new line after `return` will return `undefined` and ignore the subsequent code, as is happening here.

See why it is happening (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) here:

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#automatic_semicolon_insertion

Comment: @Alasfair: Thanks a lot! That was the main error!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 return
    React.createElement("table", null,
        React.createElement("tr", null, 
            React.createElement("td", null, "${this.props.first}"), 
            React.createElement("td", {style: "text-align: right"}, "${this.props.second}")
        )
    )
```

to

```
return (
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{`${this.props.first}`}</td>
      <td>{`${this.props.second}`}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
)
```

I don't know why you are using `createElement` for just displaying table...

Comment: I thought by eliminating JSX, I can also eliminate a source of error! I will also try the JSX version!

Comment: The error is the new line after `return` - JSX makes no difference

Comment: @Sowam: Thanks a lot ,JSX version also works! Now I have an error concering style mapping, but thats another topic!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code working fine.

1. As @Alastair mentioned you shouldn't move return statement to new line.
2. You have to enclose template literals with ``.
3. style attribute syntax is wrong, you've to use it like object.

```js
class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement("table", null,
      React.createElement("tr", null,
        React.createElement("td", null, `${this.props.first}`),
        React.createElement("td", {
          style: {
            textAlign: "right"
          }
        }, `${this.props.second}`)
      )
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyTable, {
    first: "erste",
    second: "zweite"
  }, null),
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <!-- Load React. -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="myTableNOjsx.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you were actually returning nothing. This is the correct syntax for your return statement:

```js
    render(){ 
      return(
        React.createElement("table", null,
            React.createElement("tr", null, 
                React.createElement("td", null, `${this.props.first}`), 
                React.createElement("td", {style: {textAlign: "right"}}, `${this.props.second}`)
            )
        )
      )  
    }
```

Also notice that you where using template literals with `"` but you need to use backticks: ``

You also are using styles as strings. In React, styles are objects `style: { width: "100%" }`